# Selenium webdriver in Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to right click a link in a web page and open it in a new window with context click method of Action class. Below is the code which I got from few references. But this doesn't work. Can someone help to find out what is the mistake I'm doing here?

```
package webDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class RightClick {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
    String baseUrl = "https://www.google.com";
    System.setProperty("WebDriver.gecko.driver","C://geckodriver");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.linkText("About"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.contextClick(select).perform();
    builder.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
}
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

When we click a link while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, the resulting `link` generally opens in new window.

See if this helps:

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("About"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).click(link).keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, this works with opening in a new window.
But why doesn't this work, when we try with context click and try to choose from that.

Comment: If the answer helped, please mark the answer as accepted. Regarding your query, in your code's last line you have not written `.build().perform()`. Probably that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code your problem will be solved,Its working I have tried it for you,Kindly revert back if you have got it.

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=sxWqWoDHL6SwX7PXjaAH");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fsl']/a[3]"));
        String linkToOpen= element.getAttribute("href");
        System.out.println(linkToOpen);
        Robot r = new Robot();                          
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
        r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T); 
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); 
        r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);    
        //To switch to the new tab
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));

        //To navigate to new link/URL in 2nd new tab
        driver.get(linkToOpen);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works with firefox, but not with chrome. With chrome, I'm getting the below exception while getting window handles ---- java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)

Comment: Also, is there any way, we can make it work with context click too

Comment: The above code is written for chrome only,not for firefox

Comment: and for the exception you print the size of lab and give the value for get() method.